# Twitter Provider, doesn't redirect me into the Callback

Tags: php, twitter-oauth, provider, laravel-socialite, laravel-8

Facebook, LinkedIn, Google, GitHub, GitLab, Bitbucket and many others support OAuth2 for user-based authentication. but Twitter still using Oauth1 only .

```
if ($provider === "twitter") {
   return Socialite::driver($provider)
    ->userFromTokenAndSecret(
     env("TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN"),
     env("TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")
    )
    ->redirect();
```

Running into this issue :

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\One\User::redirect()
```

I want to be redirected into the callback :

```
https://example.com/api/login/twitter/callback
```

Any Help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Socialite::with($provider)->redirect();` to redirect. But you have to first store the callback URL in your `config/services.php` file with your ids.

```
'twitter' => [
        'client_id' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_CLIENT_SECRET'),Client Secret
        'redirect' => env('TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL'),
    ],
```

Then inside your callback function `Socialite::driver($provider)->user();` to get the user.

Comment: Hi @Kavinda Perera,

I have already used it : 

`Socialite::driver($provider)->user();`




Thanks a lot !!